# VIMEO (Pro) get JSON response help (PHP/CURL)

Tags: php, json, curl, vimeo

I have a Vimeo PRO account.
I have protected videos uploaded.
Videos are also set to ONLY be embeddable on my domains (set in the video settings)

I am -not- grasping how to use their examples  (sorry, for me the examples do not include real working samples for me,..or at least how to implement them to understand.. so I'm hoping to get some help)

Not clear on all the OAuth2, Oembed... authentication stuff either.. which I believe is where my problem lies.

I was following this gitHub example:

```
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/blob/master/oembed/php-example.php
```

(looks to be pretty old?)

I'm looking to get JSON data returned for a video when an ID is passed along.

I was/am under the impression that I need to 'authenticate' before I can get my response/return data?

Is this best done in the CURL header or something?

Can someone guide me a bit more?  (shouldnt be this hard!)  haha..

Here is my code:

```
$video_endpoint = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/';
$video_url = '171811266';

//JSON url
//$json_url = $video_endpoint . '.json?url=' . rawurlencode($video_url);
//this fixes the cURL approach
$json_url = $video_endpoint . rawurlencode($video_url);

// Curl helper function
function curl_get($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization : bearer xxxxxx'));
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

$vimeoJSON = json_decode((curl_get($json_url)));
var_dump($vimeoJSON);
```

And I get this response:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> string(52) "You must provide a valid authenticated access token." }
```

questions are:

1.) Is this even a valid approach?  (assuming I just need to append some lines of code to the CURL header to send my auth over before getting a response?)

2.) How do I update my CURL snippet to work with VIEMO authentication?

I'm trying to keep this as CLEAN/SIMPLE as I can (for the JSON call/return portion)..

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

update:

this code does NOT work:

```
$access_token = 'xxx';    
$video_endpoint = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/';
$video_url = '171811266';

$json_url = $video_endpoint . '.json?url=' . rawurlencode($video_url);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $json_url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer ".$access_token
      ),
    ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

The video I want to use is located here:

https://vimeo.com/171811266/5822169b48

IT IS A PRIVATE VIDEO.   (not sure you'll be able to see it)..

When I use the latest version of the code posted above.. I get this response:

```
{"error":"The requested video could not be found"}
```

Is this because its a PRIVATE video?

(actually I just set the video to be able to be viewed by anyone.. and I still got the same error/response)  (not found)

If so.. what is the fix to use MY videos.. that are set to private... but use them on my site/domain still?

===========================================================================

FINAL UPDATE:

Trying to use the code in the readme example:
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Trying to use (un-successfully) the LIB @Dashron pointed me too..  I cant even seem to get the basics to work from the GIT Page:

Code:

```
//project vars 
$client_id = 'xxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxx';
$access_token = 'xxx';

$redirect_uri = 'http://domain.com/file.php'; //where do I redirect them back to?  the page where I have the embeded video at?
// scope is an array of permissions your token needs to access. You can read more at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#scopes
$scopes = Array('public', 'private');
$state = 'Ldhg0478y';

require("Vimeo/autoload.php");

$lib = new Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);


// build a link to Vimeo so your users can authorize your app. //whatever that means and is for?
$url = $lib->buildAuthorizationEndpoint($redirect_uri, $scopes, $state);

// redirect_uri must be provided, and must match your configured uri
$token = $lib->accessToken(code, redirect_uri);

// usable access token
var_dump($token['body']['access_token']);

// accepted scopes
var_dump($token['body']['scope']);

// use the token
$lib->setToken($token['body']['access_token']);
```

I get this error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected Fatal error: Class 'Vimeo\Vimeo' not found in /usr/www/users/aaemorg/aaem.org/video/vimeo_lib.php
```

Seems like its not creating instantiating my $lib object/class??

(I know I'm not great at high level PHP class/code... but this absurdly hard just to get a JSON response for video I own to embed (again) on a site I own as well)

Any direction would be appreciated?

======================================================================

**Update:  "what worked for me"..**

I am appreciate the link to the 'official' library.. but the readme examples just didnt work for me...

To keep things nice and easy for others who may be new to the Vimeo API stuff as well..  here is a quick and dirty, simple code sample to get you up and running:

```
<?
//include offifial library
require("Vimeo/autoload.php");
$client_id = 'xxx';
$client_secret = 'xxx';
$access_token = 'xxx';
$video_id = 'xxx'; 
$lib = new Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token);
$video_response = $lib->request('/videos/'.$video_id);

//dont really need this, but included in case there is some data you need to display
$token_response = $lib->clientCredentials();

//example of parsing out specific data from the array returned
//name/title
echo $video_response['body']['name'] . '<br><br>';


?>
```

Comment: @Cfreak -

Thanks for the assist!  (I glazed right over that!)

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is very, very old. It is actually part of a different API, and no longer relevant.

The Library you should be using is located here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php with many examples in the readme, and the examples directory!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. since I couldnt get the CURL approach to work (unfortunately..  as I just want a simple JSON return to use as I see fit).. 

I will try to use the library you linked to.  It looks like a A LOT of extra stuff.. just to get a simple JSON return though?

Can you explain to me why if these are MY video.. and I want to display them on MY domains (also used in the video settings for privacy/embedding)...  why do I need to this authentication stuff?

I'm not fully grasping why I need to send a user to vimeo page/site in order for a user to approve/accept ANYTHING?

Comment: I just want to embed PRIVATE videos on my own site?

I want to get a JSON return (using .PHP) so I display the video itself (iFrame or whatever)...   display the description..and the download videos all on my site  (again video and site are owned by me)

Comment: I updated the original post with my failed attempt using the link you provided. Errors outs on the $url line.. 

Any advice/direction on how to get a simple JSON response for a video ID?  (and maybe clrarify why I need to do all this auth stuff for video "I" own.. and only being embedded on sites "I" own as well?

Thanks!

Comment: working example(s) posted in original post... including the updated CURL version/approach is so desired to NOT use the official library.

Comment: You have to generate access tokens for other users. You can generate your own access tokens manually on your app page at developer.vimeo.com/apps

Comment: I did, and used them in the example posted in the original post (using the 'readme' tutorials/steps)  I obviously just 'xxx'd' them out when posted here.


I also posted another snippet after showing what -did- work for me. (using the same lib)

Those few lines of code gave me what I was looking for. A simple JSON array/object return for me to pick apart and display as I see fit on my page.  (including the iframe code..etc)

I even got the original cURL version working too by altering the 1 line to be:

    `$json_url = $video_endpoint . rawurlencode($video_url);`

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me

Please follow this step before

Under video settings : General->privacy, Change `Who can watch` select box to **Anyone**.

```
$url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/388591356';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$headers = array(); 
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer 969329f9b5b3882d74d1b39297528242";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$final_result = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $result), true );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_result);
```